# multiple form validation using jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I have a single form, having 2 buttons, and when both buttons are clicked, they would validate differently. But I am having trouble doing that. I have the following form that looks like this:

```
<form id="testform" method="post">
   <input type="textarea" name="remarks" />
   <input type="file" name="files[0]"/>
   <button id="button1">Button 1</button>
   <button id="button2">Button 2</button>
</form>
```

How do I use the validation plugin in such a way that when button1 is clicked, it only validates the `remarks` field, where as for button2 it validates both the `remarks` and the `files[0]` fields? I have tried using the following but it doesn't seem to work...

```
$("#testform").validate({
            //e.preventDefault();
            rules : {
                remarks: {
                    required: true,
                }
            },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'text-danger',
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.attr('type') == 'radio') {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parents('label').siblings(':last'));
                } else if (element.parents('div').hasClass('input-group')) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parents('.input-group'));
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to have two separate routines, one for each button, and one routine does X when one button is clicked, and when the other button is clicked the separate routine does Y.